# problem with calculating polynomial with Estrin algorithm in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, math, data-structures

I am new to the concepts of algorithms and have started implementing them in Java.
I tried to implement the Estrin's algorithm in Java but unfortunately it does not work

Can anyone help me with where the problem is and how to fix it?

```
import static java.lang.Math.log;
import static java.lang.Math.pow;

public class EstrinMethod {
    static int Estin(int poly[] , int x)
{
    int shift ;
    int degree = 0;
    double npower2 = 0 ;
    int n = 0;
    double numsteps = 0;

    int nearestPowerOfTwo = 0;
    if (nearestPowerOfTwo % n != 0)
    {
        shift = nearestPowerOfTwo - (n % nearestPowerOfTwo);
        npower2 = degree + shift;

    }
    else
    {
        shift = 0;
        npower2 = n;
    }

    numsteps = pow(2,log(npower2));


    return 0;
}

public static void  main(String[] args)
{
    int[] poly = {2,-6,2,-1};
    int x = 3;
    System.out.println("Value of polynomial in Estrin's method is "
            + Estin(poly,x));
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Comment: With this being said: You have a division by zero right off the bat. `int n = 0` and then some lines down you say `if (nearestPowerOfTwo % n != 0)` ? It seems to me that your initial values are incorrect.

Also please try to state exactly what your problem is.

Comment: Your solution will require some loop or some recursive call. As it is right now, it contains a 'return 0;' statement, which will always just give you a value of 0. The method doesn't look like a feasible start to an implementation. Perhaps you can find a step-by-step pseudocode description of the algorithm (and paste it into your code as a code comment) and then try to translate the pseudocode into java. And then you can more clearly describe what parts of the algorithm you are having trouble implementing